# Unable to get the text boxes and labels to be printed dynamically in php and HTML

Tags: php

I have this code and it should print labels with text boxes for people to fill in information. It takes a text like : $tokens = "*noun *noun *verb" and should print to the user a table that has :

Noun: (text box to be filled)
Noun: (text box to be filled)
verb: (text box to be filled) etc.

but it is not working

```
echo "<form action=\"storygenerated.php\" method=\"post\">
        <input name=\"fields\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$tokens\" />
        <input name=\"story\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$story\" />
        <table>";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tokenArray); $i++) {
    $fieldWords = split('_',$tokensArray[$i]);
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $fieldWords[0];
    for ($j = 1; $j < count($fieldWords); $j++) {
        echo " ".$fieldWords[$j];
    }
    echo ":";
    echo "</td><td><input name=\"$tokensArray[$i]\" type=\"text\" /></td></tr>";
}
```

which is from this code that is generating the text $tokens

```
$storyArray = split(' ', $story);
$tokens = ""; // space-delimited list of fields
$tokensArray=array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($storyArray); $i++) {
    if ($storyArray[$i][0] == '*') {  
        $tokens .= $storyArray[$i] . " ";
        $tokensArray[] = $storyArray[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Table abuse! Read http://locus.forestninja.net/2009/02/13/designing-web-forms-label-placement-primary-vs-secondary-actions/ (and the documents it links to) for info on form design and use CSS to lay out your form.

Comment: **@outis:** outside the scope of the question, plus I'm pretty sure this is a homework assignment. Wasting time on designing a form is pretty useless in this case. Go troll elsewhere.

Comment: @Andrew: which is why it's a comment. How is advocating usability trolling? If it's homework, OP can decide how far to go. Also, the OP won't be in school forever.

Comment: this is not a homework assignment, i am just trying to be better in php :) thanks for all of you anyway :)

Comment: @Andrew: I was also advocating semantic HTML and separating presentation from structure, all very important for OP to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few things wrong in your code. I'll start with the first segment.

1. In your `for` condition, you are using `$tokenArray` instead of `$tokensArray` (missing `s`) in your `count()`.
2. In your last echo, since you are using a compound variable name (`$tokensArray[$i]`), you should enclose it in braces as such: `{$tokensArray[$i]}`

The corrected code for the first part is the following:

```
echo "<form action=\"storygenerated.php\" method=\"post\">
        <input name=\"fields\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$tokens\" />
        <input name=\"story\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$story\" />
        <table>";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tokensArray); $i++) {
    $fieldWords = split('_',$tokensArray[$i]);
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $fieldWords[0];
    for ($j = 1; $j < count($fieldWords); $j++) {
        echo " ".$fieldWords[$j];
    }
    echo ":";
    echo "</td><td><input name=\"{$tokensArray[$i]}\" type=\"text\" /></td></tr>";
}
```

---

There is also a few performance improvements that could be done which would increase readability and simplify your code.

- Since you are using characters to split your string, use `explode()` instead of `split()`. `split()` uses a regular expression to split the string versus `explode()` which simply uses plain characters.
- The whole `$fieldWords` split and loop could be replaced by a one liner:

---

```
echo str_replace('_', ' ', $tokensArray[$i]);
```

- You are separating your `$story` string manually when using a regular expression would be so much simpler:

---

```
preg_match_all('/\*\w+/m', $story, $tokensArray);
$tokensArray = $tokensArray[0];
$tokens = implode(' ', $tokensArray); // Space delimited list of tokens
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i really appreciate your help. I asked another question, i really appreciate the help i am getting in this website :)

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
if ($storyArray[$i][0] == '*') {
```

you check just if the string is a string with 1 character equal to an asterisk so I suppose your `$tokensArray[]` is always empty.

I hope you'll modify the lines

```
echo $fieldWords[0];
for ($j = 1; $j < count($fieldWords); $j++) {
    echo " ".$fieldWords[$j];
}
```

with

```
foreach ($fieldWords as $word) {
    echo " ".$word;
}
```

Comment: Wrong, `$storyArray[$i][0]` checks if the first character of `$storyArray[$i]` is a `*`. Strings are arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I was not doing. The first one is that I was dealing with story like an array even though it is not, it is a string. The second is that I was not actually replacing the variables with the value I wanted to be published. I solved the problem with the help of the people who posted some information here. Thank you all.